# Use findall with arg

Tags: prolog

I'm learning Prolog and I try to rewrite the `univ` predicate:

```
?- foo(hello, X) =.. List.
List = [foo, hello, X]

?- Term =.. [baz, foo(1)].
Term = baz(foo(1))
```

I already wrote a first version that works well:

```
get_args(_, Arity, Arity, []).
get_args(T, Arity, N, [Arg|Args]) :-
    I is N + 1,
    arg(I, T, Arg),
    get_args(T, Arity, I, Args).

univ(T, [Functor|Args]) :-
    length(Args, Arity),
    functor(T, Functor, Arity),
    get_args(T, Arity, 0, Args),
    !
```

I wanted to try another way to implement it. So, I rewrite this one by using `findall` and `arg`:

```
univ(T, [Functor|Args]) :-
    length(Args, Arity),
    functor(T, Functor, Arity),
    findall(Arg, arg(_, T, Arg), Args),
    !.
```

This one doesn't work well. Here is an example:

```
?- univ(a(C, D, E), L).
L = [a, _G1312, _G1315, _G1318].
?- univ(T, [a, C, D, E]).
T = a(_G1325, _G1326, _G1327).
```

Thus, I have a simple question: is it possible to use `arg` with `findall` in order to retrieve the name of each arguments?

Comment: `findall/3` *copies* variables. To restore the original bindings, you can copy the subterms together with all variables (see `term_variables/2`) and later unify the common variables, thus also restoring the original subterms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @mat, findall/3 copies variables. You can use bagof/3 instead:

```
univ(T, [Functor|Args]) :-
    length(Args, Arity),
    functor(T, Functor, Arity),
    bagof(Arg, I^arg(I, T, Arg), Args),
    !.

?- univ(a(C, D, E), L).
L = [a, C, D, E].
```

This different behaviour wrt findall/3 and setof/3 can also be useful when you need to handle attributed variables.

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks a lot!